How can I use a DWS600BL washing machine BLDC motor outside the washing machine?
I have a DWS600BL 3 phase BLDC 310V motor which was originally in a Samsung WF71184 washing machine.
I want to use it outside the washing machine but I do not know how to use it and if I need some additional parts of the washing machine. There are 4 wires together and 3 wires together going to the motor.

use it to do what?

Do you want to use it as a motor or an alternator? || Use as an alternator is easy-ish and you need just the motor and a bridge rectifier. if you want DC out. || To use as a motor you need a suitably high voltage 3 phase brushless DC motor controller. This could be the one embedded in the washing machine control system. It will have power transistors (usually FETs or IGBTs) and control electronics. Utilising the controller would very likely require significant electronic knowledge. || OR you could see if people are using these aftermarket as motors. ||

In either case you'll want the Hall effect rotation sensors mounted on or by the motor. || For lower voltage operation windings that are in series can be paralleled/

Do you want to use it as a motor or an alternator?
Use as an alternator is easy-ish and you need just the motor, and a bridge rectifier if you want DC out.
To use as a motor you need a suitably high voltage 3 phase brushless DC motor controller. This could be the one embedded in the washing machine control system. It will have power transistors (usually FETs or IGBTs) and control electronics. Utilising the controller would very likely require significant electronic knowledge.
OR you could see if people are using these aftermarket as motors.
In either case you'll want the Hall effect rotation sensors mounted on or by the motor.
For lower voltage operation windings that are in series can be paralleled.
